# Mobile browser: zoom after orientation change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hammer.js

I'm developing one-page site (webapp in fact). When I tested it on a mobile device, I noticed that mobile browsers change zoom lvl after orientation change. Unfortunately I can't just set user-scalable to 0. Is any other way to get rid of this problem? I think maybe I can do my own zoom mechanizm via HammerJS, and then set user-scalable to 0, but it work slow and jerky... Any idea, how resolve this?

P.S.
I use AngularJS as my framework, and HammerJS to manipulate other touch events

Comment: Have you tried this already? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help :(

Comment: Don't believe that. Which device & browser does changes zoom level between "portrait/landscape" format?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 with Android 4.1 and Chrome 42, but I found info about this problem on many devices (i.e. on iPhone)